# javascript asynchronous callback lifetime

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, websocket, xmlhttprequest

I am new to javascript but have some c++ background, so the following confuses me: I create some WebSocket connection from browser like this:

```
function ready() {
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

    connection.onmessage = function(msg) {        
        console.log(msg.data);
    };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

the `connection` variable is local so the reference to `WebSocket` object goes out of scope when `ready()` exits. My expectation is that the connection should die along with the callback on it, but somehow I am still able to get `connection.onmessage` callbacks. My understanding that it's not related to javascript scoping but a matter of how `WebSocket` connections are organized internally. Is it so? Could you explain this behavior please. I believe the same goes for every asynchronous api in javascript, another example:

```
function get(url) {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", url);

    req.onload = function() {
        console.log(req.response);
    }

    req.send();
}

get("file.json");
```

So it seems like callbacks are not tied to objects they are put on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a garbage collected language.  That means that an object or contents of a variable in Javascript is NOT automatically freed when it goes out of scope in a function.  Instead, the object lives until there is no more active code that can reach it.

So, in your function, you set up an event handler on the `connection` object.  As long as there is active code somewhere that still has a reference to that connection object, then Javascript will not garbage collected that object.

In this particular case, the `connection` object represents a live TCP connection to another host and there's both Javascript code and native code behind that TCP connection that still has a reference to the connection object and can still fire events on it.  The Javascript engine knows that this code still has a reference to this object so it will not garbage collect it.  And, sure enough anytime a new packet arrives on the webSocket connection, it will call your onMessage handler.

The way to make that connection object eligible for garbage collection would be to close the connection.  That will cause the webSocket code and the native code behind it to clear any references it has to the connection object and it will then be eligible for garbage collection.

In Javascript, one should never think of function local variables as having a lifetime strictly associated with when the function returns.  You will shortly find that (particularly due to the asynchronous nature of many operations in Javascript) that local variables in a function stay alive long after a function returns and this turns out to be very, very useful.

The mental model that I use (which may or may not be exactly how it's implemented) that helps me understand all this is to never think of local variables in a function as being allocated on a stack frame.  Instead, think of them as dynamically allocated on a heap.  They can live on that heap for as long as needed, including long after the function has already returned.  The garbage collector will free them when no code is using them any more or could use them any more.

Because of asynchronous callbacks (like in your example), such a callback can easily cause the local variables to stay alive long after the containing function has already returned.

> the connection variable is local so the reference to WebSocket object goes out of scope when ready() exits

Things in function scope are not automatically freed when the containing function returns.  They are not allocated on the stack like they would be in C/C++.  They are garbage collected and will be freed when no longer being used.

> My expectation is that the connection should die along with the callback on it, but somehow I am still able to get connection.onmessage callbacks

See above.  Local variables in Javascript can live long after their host function returns.

> My understanding that it's not related to javascript scoping but a matter of how WebSocket connections are organized internally.

This is not particularly webSocket-specific.  As described above, this is because of Javascript garbage collection.  The code that manages the (still alive) webSocket connection has a live reference to the `connection` object and thus prevents it from being garbage collected.  To terminate that live reference, you would close the webSocket connection and then the code that manages the webSocket connection would clear it's references to the connection object and then it would be eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation! I might not have been clear but in my example the particular thing that confused me was that both connection object and callback function object were local variables that had no reference to them from global root object, but only cross references to each other, so I thought they both should be GC'd. I missed that there is actually a live TCP connection underneath. So with the mental model you described I guess I should not really care about accessing a deleted object in similar scenarios, when javascript asynchronous API is involved. Thanks again!

Comment: @TerentyRezman - You cannot reference a deleted object in Javascript because if you have a reference to it, it will not get garbage collected.  And, event handlers on an underlying OS level object (like a socket) will also cause things not to get garbage collected while that object is alive and can still generate events you are registered for.

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners in JavaScript are more like subscriptions. Until you unsubscribe you will continue to receive information. If you want to close this off after receiving one message, you can set your `onload` function to close the connection immediately after getting information:

```
function ready() {
    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000');

    connection.onmessage = function(msg) {        
        console.log(msg.data);
        // this closes the websocket connection
        connection.close();
    };
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
```

**Update**

In general your concern is about how closures work in JavaScript. I can't link to it directly but if you go [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Performance_considerations) and scroll up 3 code blocks there's an example regarding callbacks and closures. It's more in regards to iterations but has some relevant pieces of information. The entire article is definitely worth reading to get a better handle on some of the nuances of scopes in JavaScript.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that the connection and callback stay alive after going out of scope as local variables, not that I want to terminate it) I mean where the references to them exist so they are not GC'ed

Comment: The `onload` is a callback that will remain active so long as there is an active connection. Leaving scope does not close the connection because you haven't set any condition that closes it.

Comment: so you saying that javascript WebSocket object just represents websocket connection to javascript environment but the connection exist somewhere internally, and the callback is not tied to javascript WebSocket object but to that internal connection, so when javascript WebSocket object dies, connection and callback still persists, right ?

Comment: @TerentyRezman This isn't anything regarding Websockets in particular; this is behavior of callbacks in general. XHR, Websocket, and numerous other APIs offer similar approaches to allow your program to respond to events. When an event occurs with listeners, all listeners are then run in the order they were attached. This differs from saying `onmessage` or `onload` which removes all other listeners. When the callback is executed it must have the scope of the listener in order to process. As a result `connection` will not be GC'd until the connection is closed and all references are gone.

Comment: ok, so attaching a listener to an object that what makes the object persistent in memory? I am just trying to figure out the exact thing that keeps it alive when the obvious references are gone

Comment: The GC in JavaScript is not really something we can actively control and operates when it finds the need to. But there are a couple of rules that govern when it can execute. For a given scope if nothing references what's inside the scope, then it can be garbage collected. However, if there are unresolved items like `Promise` or callbacks (like event listeners), the scope remains available. More specifically, the websocket connection was never closed so it's in memory and it's callback for `onmessage` exists inside of the `ready` function. So the contents of `ready` can not be GC'd.

Comment: with all these rules on javascript scoping in tutorials, when they teach about lexical scopes it is not clear that some objects (event listeners, promises, etc) implicitly keep references when immediate objects seem to die. Well, thank you for your time, you've cleared things up a bit

Comment: @TerentyRezman Sure thing, glad to help! Also I updated my answer with some documentation on closures that I think you'll find helpful.